# PHP how to change the location of an uploaded picture

Tags: php, ajax, image

I think I have managed to upload an image via AJAX to a PHP file, I am now trying to move it to a known location, here is my code:

```
$allowedExtensions = array('JPEG', 'JPG', 'PNG', 'GIF');
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if (in_array($extension, $allowedExtensions)) {
    if (file_exists("../pictures/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"])) {
        echo $_FILES["image"]["name"] . " already exists";
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["name"], "../pictures/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
        echo "Moved to ". "../pictures/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];

    }
}
```

When run I am getting the echo saying it has been moved to "../pictures/capture.JPG" but when I look in that folder, its not there.

Any ideas why? I also don't know what the `["name"]` does so an explanation of that would also be great thanks!

Comment: You're simply assuming that the `move_uploaded_file` statement executed successfully. Never do that. ***Always*** check the return values to see if the statement succeeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is a minor error in your code. When PHP uploads an image, it keeps it in a temporary directory. So in order to move, you should do this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "../pictures/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
```

Note the `tmp_name` above. If the rest of your code is ok, this must work!

Comment: Thank you! This worked! what is the second [] (i.e. `["tmp_name"]`) for? what does it do exactly?

Comment: I had the same problem some months ago. I lost a lot of time with this! I am not sure about this, but I discovered that when php uploads the image, it keeps the image in a temporary directory. So I think  "tmp_name" is the way to tell php to get the image in this directory to save in the desired one. You are wellcome!